# F distribution with the denominator degrees of freedom infinitely large

Tags: limits, statistics, probability-distributions, infinity, chi-squared

> **Definition** Let $W$ be a chi-squared random variable with $m$ degrees of freedom and let $V$ be a chi-squared random variable with $n$ degrees of freedom, where $W$ and $V$ are independently distributed. Then $\frac{W/m}{V/n}$ has $F_{m,n}$ distribution.
>
> **Limiting case:** $\frac{W}{m}$ has $F_{m,\infty}$ distribution.

I am wondering how $\frac{V}{n}$ goes to $1$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$. In my view, $\frac{V}{n}$ should go to $0$ instead, because $n$ goes to $\infty$ in the denominator. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define $F_{m,n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the variable $V$ is not a fixed distribution; it varies with $n$. In fact the chi-square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom is distributed like $\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2$, where $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$ are iid standard normal variables. So  $V/n$ has expectation $1$. [You can also look up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution), or calculate, that the variance of $V$ is $2n$, so the variance of $V/n$ is $2/n$, which implies that $V/n$ converges in probability to one as $n\to\infty$.